# How to iterate list of string in a cartesian way?

Tags: java

I have a string that has been partitioned into 5 char each of the element:

> ss="A4A12B2B16A1B01A1B23S1B32A1A32B1B44B2A44A4C16A3D15A4D01A5D23A4E20B1F24A2F17A1F01B0G16A5C34A4C43A5C53A3D50A4D61S4E50A0F51A1F67S2E46B1E31A1F30A2G36A1G41B1G52";

```
List<String> parts = new ArrayList<>();
int len = ss.length();
int partitionSize=5;
for (int i = 0; i < len; i += partitionSize) {
            parts.add(ss.substring(i, Math.min(len, i + partitionSize)));
        }
System.out.println(parts)
```

The code will then print out something like this:

> > [A4A12, B2B16, A1B01, A1B23, S1B32, A1A32, B1B44, B2A44, A4C16, A3D15, A4D01, A5D23, A4E20, B1F24, A2F17, A1F01, B0G16, A5C34, A4C43, A5C53, A3D50, A4D61, S4E50, A0F51, A1F67, S2E46, B1E31, A1F30, A2G36, A1G41, B1G52]

I have a foo function that only takes two string input. For each i, the array will increase from [A4A12, B2B16] to [A4A12, B2B16, A1B01] to [A4A12, B2B16, A1B01, A1B23] and so on until the list is exhausted...

When i==0, I want the function to evaluate foo(A4A12,B2B16)

When i==1, I want the function to evaluate foo(A4A12,B2B16) then foo(B2B16,A1B01)

When i==3, I want the function to evaluate foo(A4A12,B2B16) then foo(A4A12,A1B01), then foo(A4A12,A1B23), then foo(B2B16,A1B01), then foo(B2B16,A1B23), then foo(A1B01,A1B23).

This is what I tried so far

```
List<List> parts1 = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i=0;i<set.size();i++){
         parts1.add(parts.subList(0,i+1));//increase the size of the array for every iteration
         for (int j=0;j<parts1.size();i++){//how to loop this in a Cartesian way??
                        if(foo(parts.get(j), parts.get(j+1))){
                              return true;}
```

Of course the loop will not iterate in an exhaustive/Cartesian's way isn't it? Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Do you want to evaluate the foo function for all the first (i+1) pair combinations?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to iterate in a Cartesian way, you could do as follow:

```
String ss = "A4A12B2B16A1B01A1B23";
List<String> parts = new ArrayList<>();
int len = ss.length();
int partitionSize=5;
for (int i=0; i<len; i+=partitionSize)
    parts.add(ss.substring(i, Math.min(len, i + partitionSize)));

for (int i=1; i<parts.size(); i++) {
    List<String> pairs = new LinkedList<>();
    for (int j=0;j<=i;j++)
        pairs.add(parts.get(j));
    while(!pairs.isEmpty()) {
        String cur1 = pairs.get(0);
        Iterator<String> it2 = pairs.iterator();
        it2.next(); //discard first element which of course exists
        while(it2.hasNext()) {
            String cur2 = it2.next();
            if(foo(cur1, cur2)) {
                    //...
            }
        }
        pairs.remove(0);
    }
    //end processing of the i-th cartesian product
}
```

Note that if you want that for the i-th cartesian product, all the pairs have to return true for the foo call, then you have to use a boolean variable initialised to true and, if it is true that exists a pair such that for this pair the foo function returns false then you set that boolean variable to false. At the end of the i-th cartesian product processing, you can check that boolean variable.